# Как определить чётное ли число?

Tags: java

Задача состоит в следующем:
Вывести следующее после текущего чётное число. Числа целые.

Пример: Входные данные: 5, Выходные данные: 6.
или Входные данные: 6, Выходные данные: 8.

Проблема в том, что использовать конструкцию if или циклы нельзя. При скором размышлении и поиске похожих решений в поисковике ничего полезного не обнаружил.
Подскажите пожалуйста, какие алгоритмы бывают?

Язык Java.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Если нет никаких суровых ограничений на размер исходных данных, то подошло бы что-то такое

```
x = x+2 - (x&1);
```

или

```
x = (x+2)&(-2)
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. А как работает логика выражения "x = (x+2)&(-2)"?

Comment: а корректно ли делать битовые операции с отрицательными цислами с точки зрения стандарта? я бы скорее писал не (-2) а (~1)...

Comment: @pavel, это ж джава, а не плюсы.

Comment: Я не в курсе, как это по стандарту, потому что всё упирается в конкретные ограничения и типы данных, а их автор вопроса не дал.

Comment: @Makis, число -2 это отрицание от 1. То есть все биты, кроме младшего равные 1. Зануляя младший бит, делаем число чётным.

Comment: кстати а для отрицательных чисел не работает)

Comment: x = x%2 == 0 ? x+2 : x++;

Comment: @pavel так вроде наоборот, это единственный вариант, который [работает для отрицательных](http://ideone.com/C88NnO) (остальные выдают на 2 больше)

Comment: @МихаилКоломиец тернарная операция вроде как подозревает условие, которое использовать нельзя

Answer (score 4):

Вариант с остатком от деления.

```
 X+2-X%2
```

Пример:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            System.out.println(i+" " + a(i));           
        }
    }

    public static int a(int x)  {return x+2-x%2;}
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, но этот вариант не работает.

Comment: @Makis что то сделали не так. class Main {
 public static void main(String[] args) {  
  for(int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
   System.out.println(i+" " + a(i));   
  }
 }
 
 public static int a(int x)  {return x+2-x%2;}
}

Comment: Вы правы, я использовал "x=X+2-X%2" вместо "a=X+2-X%2". Этот вариант тоже работает. Спасибо.

Comment: @Makis имейте ввиду, что с отрицательными числами работает не верно. В постановке задачи не указано, что числа будут только положительные.

Answer (score 2):

Еще вариант, для коллекции:

```
x=(x/2+1)*2
```

Comment: ваш вариант не корректно работает для отрицательных чисел. И мой, кстати тоже.

Comment: Да, действительно, не учел, что они могут быть отрицательными.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Even {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = -4;
        System.out.println("x=" + x + ", next even " + (x + 2 - Math.abs(x)%2));    
    }
}

x=-5, next even -4
x=-4, next even -2
x=-3, next even -2
x=-2, next even 0
x=-1, next even 0
x=0, next even 2
x=1, next even 2
x=2, next even 4
x=3, next even 4
x=4, next even 6
x=5, next even 6
```

Comment: Спасибо. Хороший вариант